# Almalinux - Extending logical drive partition after resize

Tags: fdisk, rocky-linux, partition-table

I am trying to extend the disk space on an AlmaLinux server (running on a VM), this is a live email server, so I really can't mess this up. There are other posts on this operation, but I am not quite getting the same questions. I have tagged this Rocky-Linux as Almalinux doesn't seem to be listed.

lsblk output:

```
sda                  8:0    0  130G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0   79G  0 part 
  ├─almalinux-root 253:0    0 50.4G  0 lvm  /
  ├─almalinux-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─almalinux-home 253:2    0 24.6G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                 11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Then fdisk /dev/sda - p shows:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf0b9c034

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   2099199   2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 167772159 165672960  79G 8e Linux LVM
```

So, the plan is to delete Partition 2 and create a new one with the new starting and ending sectors.

```
Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
```

Q: Is the new partition 2, type "e"?

I proceeded with "e" .. then...

```
Select (default p): e
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
First sector (2099200-272629759, default 2099200): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2099200-272629759, default 272629759): 

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Extended' and of size 129 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a LVM2_member signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o:
```

The numbers are all correct - but do I remove the signature or not? None of the notes I have followed mention this question.

After I write the partition I can run pvresize. I just don't want to mess this up.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: With `parted` you can safely enlarge partitions without deleting. Please take note that `parted` immidiatly applicates changes in opposite to fdisk, where you need to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Paladin - it was better to use parted. Equally scary, but everything went fine - No end-users with pitchforks outside my office.

After my post, I found the lvextend and xfs_growfs command, after resize2fs gave me an error.

Here are my commands, which I got from my bash_history - they might be in the wrong order, as it looks like I used them multiple times.

```
parted /dev/sda
(in parted) resizepart 2 100%
```

[exit parted]

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/almalinux/root
xfs_growfs /dev/almalinux/root
```

Anyway, I now have plenty of space for the vmail folder to use.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want to remove the signature. But there's a safer way.

Rather than deleting and recreating the existing partition, create a new one. Make it the size of the increment you want - you're expanding 79G to 129G, so you can make the new partition 50G. Then mark it as a Physical Volume, add it to the volume group that your existing partition is in, and expand the logical volume to be the full size of the volume group. Then expand your file system.